# Why is the implicit nature of super( ) a desirable feature?

Tags: python, class, multiple-inheritance, super

This is sort of an add-on question in reference to the [very popular `super( )` question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-and-init-methods). The question was basically "Why should I use `super( )`" and the answer was "Because you don't have to reference the parent class, which can be nice."

My question is...why in the world is that a good thing? Whatever happened to "Explicit is better than implicit?" Let's say I'm reading some other developer's code and I see:

```
class Foo(Bar, Baz):
    def my_method(self):
        super(Foo, self).who_knows( ) #nobody knows!
```

I now have to dig through the docs on `Bar` and `Baz` *and* all of their parent classes all the way up the tree to find out where `who_knows( )` is being called from and what it does. I also need a perfect understanding of the Method Resolution Order in order to know *which* `who_knows( )` is actually being called.

Now let's look at the same code without `super( )`:

```
class Foo(Bar, Baz):
    def my_method(self):
        Baz.who_knows(self) #ah, Baz knows
```

Much clearer, no guesswork or understanding of the MRO required.

I'm not raising this question to start an argument or a philosophical discussion. I'm just hoping that someone can show me some very clear examples in which the implicit nature of `super( )` is actually desirable because honestly I'm not seeing it.

Comment: http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/

Comment: Because cooperative base classes can make your life easier.

Comment: @MartijnPieters at the expense of anyone else reading your code?

Comment: @galarant Some people don't even understand polymorphism at all. Should we stop using this mechanism also?

Comment: @BartoszKP I don't think that's a good analogy because polymorphic operations will raise an Exception (hopefully a useful one) if you send them an object that does not support the operator. That's perfectly explicit and perfectly fine.

Comment: "I now have to dig through the docs on Bar and Baz and all of their parent classes all the way up the tree to find out where who_knows( ) is being called from and what it does." - actually, in cooperative multiple inheritance, you can't do that. You have no idea which method is the next method in the MRO. I believe the idea is that you're supposed to design the methods so that it only matters that they're called in an order induced by a valid topological sort of the inheritance graph. What this would look like in a real program, I don't know; I try to avoid complex inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are delegating implementations to other parts of code, being "explicit" about how that code is written defeats the purpose. *Knowing* exactly what is being called equates to having a *dependency* on that implementation so that if one piece of code changes the other must change also.

Consider that the problem of ambiguity still exists with the old `Baz.who_knows(self)` method. If `Baz` does not override `who_knows`, then you still don't know which of `Baz`'s superclasses define the actual implementation. So do you change that line in `Foo`'s code to point to the class that actually implements it? But if you then *do* decide to override it in `Baz`, you need to update `Foo` again (as well as *all* other subclasses).

Answer (score 2):

For this case specifically, `super(Foo, self).who_knows()` is not a good thing at all. I would just do `self.who_knows()`.

`super()` is commonly used when overriding the method with the same name from parent class.